# Extract column value using REGEXEXTRACT with ARRAYFORMULA

Tags: regex, google-sheets, split, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a column in Google Sheets with values like `1(current), 2(current)`, etc. I am getting these values from google form response.

I want to extract only the integer from cell value as 1,2,3.. so on.
I am able to use `SPLIT(A2, "(current)")` for cells. But this does not get applied for new values from form response.

I found that **ARRAYFORLMULA** can be used for applying a formula to new responses from forms, but somehow it isn't working. I tried them as mentioned below, but I am not sure if I am using it correctly.

`=ArrayFormula(QUERY( SPLIT(E2:E,"(current)")))`

`=ArrayFormula(SPLIT(E2:E,"(current)"))`

**Can someone help with how to achieve above answer with `REGEXEXTRACT`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(E2:E, "\d+")))
```

Comment: It works if I use it separately. But for a new response, it does not work. I have a header row. And I have kept this formula in G2. Do I need to do something else in sheet? Also gives out error as: `"Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in G3."`

Comment: @ShivaniShinde yes, put it into 1st row like: `={"header name here"; ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(E2:E, "\d+")))}`

Comment: Hey thanks, that worked! Is there any way to apply condition? I have values in column as 1, 2,etc as well( i.e. just the integers). So for those values, it gives me error as `Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 1 expects text values. But '3' is a number and cannot be coerced to a text.` Can this be done?

Comment: sure, use: `={"header name here"; ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(E2:E), "\d+")))}`

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! I wasted so much time in trying out IFS. This was quick fix. : )